# RegExp Named-Groups & Conditional statements - Is there an "IF con1 OR con2 THEN (pattern)"?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, if-statement, pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a semi-advanced RegExp pattern to parse out some "macros" in some text. The pattern uses *[Named Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)* and *[Conditional Statements](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)*.

A basic example of using both of them together would be something like:

```
(?<test>a)?b(?(test)c|d)
```

The first part (before the **b**), is matching for the letter **a**, assigning it to the *named-group* `test` if it is successfully matched.

The second part (after the **b**), is the conditional statement, which basically reads:

> If `test` was matched, then look for **c**, otherwise, look for **d**

**My question is** - Is it possible to have an **OR** in that condition at the end?

Here's an example pattern I wrote up to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. The pattern below looks for one of two *named-groups*, then has a conditional, matching for another character, if the first *named-group* was successfully matched:

```
(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?(case1)(?P<last>c)?)
```

And just to clarify what thats doing:

1. Open up a non-capturing group, with two patterns:

   1.1. Match for the character **a**, assigning it to the *named-group* `case1` if it is successfully matched

   1.2. Match for the character **b**, assigning it to the *named-group* `case2` if it is successfully matched
2. A conditional statement at the end, which reads:

> If `case1` was successfully matched, then match for the character **c**, assigning it to the *named-group* `last` if it is successfully matched

So, if you wanted to change it in such a way that step **2** instead would read:

> If `case1` **OR** `case2` was successfully matched, then match for the character **c**, assigning it to the *named-group* `last` if it is successfully matched

I have tried all of the following:

```
(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?(case1|case2)(?P<last>c)?) 
(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?(?:(case1)|(case2))(?P<last>c)?)
(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?(case1,case2)(?P<last>c)?)
# Error (for 3 above): Invalid group structure, unmatched parenthesis

(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?:(?(case1)(?P<last>c)?)|(?(case2)(?P<last>c)?)) 
# Error: Subpattern name declared more than once
```

So I'm kinda lost as to what else to do. I created a **[Regex101.com instance](https://regex101.com/r/lZ6rO3/1)** with an example. You can see there's two lines in the *Text String*, and the pattern pulls out `case1` and `last` from the first line, then just `case2` from the 2nd line - The goal is to capture `last` in **both lines**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the newer _regex_ module? I don't think _re_ supports conditionals.

Comment: @sln - it does support conditionals. I have basic conditionals working just fine, just the whole **OR** thing is where I'm stuck. But I cant find any example of checking if either one of two named groups was successfully matched (anywhere, in **any language**), at least not without running into the last `Subpattern name declared more than once` error.

Comment: It is possible to nest conditionals to get the effect you want. You can put a conditional in either the yes or no part, even in nested condtionals. But, you have to follow the scoping rules so that _each_ conditional is self-contained construct, i.e. `(?(c1) yes | no-else (?(c2) yes|no) end-else)`, etc..

Comment: Hm.. And that would require you to match for the *named-group* `last` only once? and would work if either `c1` or `c2` were matched? That would work... Think you can type up a quick example in Regex101.com or something? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, 1 OR 2 match is `(?(1)|(?(2)|(?!)))` if neither matched, if fails. `     (?(1)
       |  (?(2)
            |  (?!)
          )
     )
` Its basically if yes'd then then OR is successful, else fail. When you leave the _yes_ empty it just passes through.

Comment: @sln I must be doing it wrong -> https://regex101.com/r/tH6pU0/2

Comment: I'll check it, but conversely, if 1 AND 2 must match, it's this `(?(1)(?(2)|(?!))|(?!))` i.e.      (?(1)
          (?(2)
            |  (?!)
          )
       |  
          (?!)
     )

Comment: What are the `(?!)` segments? I was assuming thats where the `last` named-group would go, but maybe not

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. Use a workaround - a capturing group for the named captures - [`((?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?)\|(?(1)(?P<last>c))`](https://regex101.com/r/yO9rE3/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hah! perfect! Thank you! Post that as an answer, and ill accept it

Comment: I'm actually not sure what your trying to do with your conditional, if either match what is it you want to do? Right now, your saying if either matched then quit, otherwise just match `c` https://regex101.com/r/tH6pU0/3

Comment: Actually @WiktorStribiżew, maybe I spoke too soon... the `(1)` will be positive for any match. And there will always be a match, but it will be different `named-groups`. [Heres what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/zF4mA2/2) I want `last` to be matched for the first two rows, but not the 3rd (meaning if `case1` **or** `case2` was matched, **but not** `case3`).. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Yeah, you want something like this https://regex101.com/r/zF4mA2/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex doesn't have such a feature, no. But there are a few tricks/workarounds that can be used depending on the situation.

- Workaround 1: If the two conditions are right next to each other, enclose them in another group:
  `(?P<case1_or_2>(?P<case1>a)|(?P<case2>b))`
- Workaround 2: Duplicate the then-pattern and else-pattern:
  `(?:(?(case1)c|d)|(?(case2)c|d))`
- Workaround 3: If possible, change your "condition"-groups to capture nothing (or, if that's not possible, simply add new groups for the sole purpose of capturing nothing. This workaround can be used in *any* scenario.), which allows you to construct an OR condition like so:
  `(?:(?:(?P=case1)|(?P=case2))c|(?!(?P=case1))(?!(?P=case2))d)`

Workaround 3 in more detail:

```
(?:
    (?P<case1>)a # if "a" is matched, case1 captures an empty string
|
    (?P<case2>)b # if "b" is matched, case2 captures an empty string
)? # if neither a nor b is matched, neither case matches at all
\|
(?: # if either case matched, match "c":
    (?: 
        (?P=case1) # match either case1
    |
        (?P=case2) # or case2
    )
    c # followed by "c"
| # if neither case matched, match "d":
    (?! # assert case1 didn't match
        (?P=case1)
    )
    (?! # assert case2 didn't match either
        (?P=case2)
    )
    d # match "d"
)
```

Comment: Workaround 1 seems to work best; Workaround 2 wont work because it will throw a `Subpattern name declared more than once` error (since the else-pattern needs to have a capturing named-group); Not sure about 3.. But I got it working just fine with Workaround #1! ([Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tH6pU0/5)) Thanks!

Comment: If you're at all curious what the finished RegExp pattern looks like.. **[Heres a demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI6cL6/5)** of it working... Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know if (in your **Workaround 1**) its possible to just assign a value `true` to the `case1_or_2`?, but still have **a** assigned to `case1` or **b** assigned to `case2`? Im using Pythons `re.groupdict()`, so id like to have the dict value of `case1_or_2` to be `true`. Heres the regex im working with: https://regex101.com/r/oV1uD2/2

Comment: @Justin You can't give it a value of `true` if there's no `true` to capture. (And if you meant the boolean `True`, no, that's not possible either.)

Answer (score 1):

**edit** Updated for *case3*
No workaround necessary..

(*Note- Conditionals don't require workarounds, they work one way.

No kludging other parts of the code to use them. Learn how to use them is the best option*)

---

I think this is what you're trying to do
`(?:(?P<case1>a)?|(?P<case2>b)?|(?P<case3>c)?)\|(?P<last>(?(case1)z?|(?(case2)z?)))`

https://regex101.com/r/tH6pU0/6

Explained

```
 (?:
      (?P<case1> a )?               # (1), Optional a
   |  (?P<case2> b )?               # (2), Optional b
   |  (?P<case3> c )?               # (3), Optional c
 )
 \|                            # Required |

 (?P<last>                     # (4 start)
      (?(case1)                     # Did case1 match
           z?                            # yes, get optional z
        |                              # or
           (?(case2)                     # Did case2 match
                z?                            # yes, get optional z
           )
      )
 )                             # (4 end)
```

Comment: That seems to work too! Im still going to check the other one, but just because the pattern is much shorter than yours. But thanks!

Comment: @Justin - You know, actually there is no need for a conditional in your situation. And fwiw, longer or shorter length regex is not a measure of performance. For example this [175,000 Word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) takes less than 5 steps to match any word.